# Unity object only moving in one direction in unity play preview

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi i am trying to learn unity and i have came through a code in which i need the object to move up and down when it reaches the limit of any side and keep it repeating. but it's just going up axis only can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class shooter_movement : MonoBehaviour {

public float shootspeed = 2;
public bool turn = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (!turn) 
    {
        transform.Translate (0, 2 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    } 
    else
    {
        transform.Translate (0, -2 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}

void OncollisionEnter2D (Collision2D Collider){

    Debug.Log ("Collision Works");
    if (GetComponent<Collider>().gameObject.tag == "wall") {

        if (turn) {

            turn = false;
        } 
        else {

            turn = true;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: It's `OnCollisionEnter2D`, not `OncollisionEnter2D`

Comment: @Hellium no it didn't work...

Comment: @Hellium the object is going up and when it touches boundary then it just starts to follow the boundary edges... but in rigidbody when i apply freeze rotation it just goes up and when touches the boundary its starting to hitting boundry again and again.

Comment: Are you sure `Collision Works` appears in your console? By the way, if you rely on collision detection, you should use [`MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) in the `FixedUpdate`

Comment: @Hellium please check the screenshot i have updated for more details.

Comment: You should write : `void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collision){ if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("wall") { // ...`

Comment: @Hellium after applying this code i got an error, it was saying wall tag not found or something so i got the main problem and solved it. not it's working even with your 1st change suggestion. thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you pick the wrong gameObject, you pick your own object instead of the one that touches.

GetComponent<>() will take the gameObject that your script attached to.
use you collider parameter instead, it's the object that touches you.

Here's the correct script, and simplified version

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "wall") {
        turn = !turn;
    }
}
```

Comment: At 1st i wrote the same code... But it's getting updated automatically to the one that's in my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's getting updated automatically to the one that's in my question" ?

Do you save your codes?